# Using Bison-generated-compiler to compile source code

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, bison

Well, so far i'm using [GNU Bison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Bison) with [Lex & Yacc](http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/) files to build a parser in C++, which is called by my program through the `yyparse()` function. Therefore the g++ compilation of my program produce an .a file that allow the user to insert some code to be parsed.

However I would like to use the generated-file to compile a whole project directory hierarchy (i.e a bunch of files). So, is Bison able to generate the result-compiler in a independent archive to allow me that? Maybe there is a simple way to parse multiple files? Or Should I manage this behavior through C++ algorithms by myself?

Thanks for the knowledge sharing!

Comment: You can tell the *lexer* to use any file you want as input.

Comment: iterate over all the files in the directory. Parser parses each file, interaction through symbol table

Comment: Right guys, but how to do it?
By now when I call `yyparse()` i can't refer to any file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bisons/yacc generated parsers do not directly read input. The parsers use the tokens extracted from the input stream by `yylex()`, leaving it entirely up to `yylex()` to read the data or otherwise access the input.

By default, the `yylex()` generated by (f)lex reads input from the input stream pointed at by the global variable `yyin`. `yylex()` does not `fopen` a file or otherwise give `yyin` a value (except for initialising it to `stdin`).

To pass multiple files through your parser:

1. Set `yyin` appropriately:

   ```
   yyin = fopen(filepath, "r");
   ```
2. Call `yyparse()`.
3. Close `yyin`.
4. Repeat as necessary.